# Finding the maximum value of $\frac{5}{4x^{2}-16x+21}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the maximum value of $$\frac{5}{4x^{2}-16x+21}$$.

I tried completing the square to get $$\frac{5}{4(x-2)^{2}+5}$$

But I'm struggling to proceed. Any hints? NO CALCULUS PLEASE.

Comment: Well you are so close, the function is maximum when denominator is minimum. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function will be maximal, if the denominator is minimal: since $4(x-2)^2+5$ is minimal, if $x=2$(in all other cases, $4(x-2)^2 > 0$), you have the answer right there.

Your answer is $x=2$, and the value is $\frac55=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly done! Since squares are positive, $(x-2)^{2} \ge 0$, so $4(x-2)^{2} + 5 \ge 5$.

Hence $$\frac{5}{4(x-2)^{2}+5} \le \frac{5}{5}=1$$